# How can I unify the number of decimal places in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, decimal

I have a more complex code compared to the examples provided and cannot imagine how I have to change the code to obtain the same number of decimal places for all bars of my bar chart. For most of the bars, R already shows two decimal places. Whenever the second decimal place is a "0", however, R only shows one decimal place. Can someone please show me how to standardize the decimal place to 2 and how to integrate the command in my code?

I already tried "digits" and specify_decimal but failed to correctly integrate it into my code (in scale_x_continuous).

```
df1_long %.>%
  ggplot(
    data = .,
    aes(
      x = xpos,
      y = val,
      fill = Ebene
  )) +
  geom_rect(aes(
      xmin = xpos - .5,
      xmax = xpos + .5,
      ymin = -Inf,
      ymax = Inf,
      fill = Problemzahl
    ),
    alpha = .3
  ) +
  geom_col(
    position = position_dodge(.5),
    colour="black",
    width = .5
  ) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(
      ymin = val - SE,
      ymax = val + SE
    ),
    position = position_dodge(.5),
    width = .2
  ) +
  geom_text(aes(
      y = val + SE + .02,
      label = val %>% str_replace('\\.', ',')
    ),
    position = position_dodge(.5)
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c(
      '#aaaaaa',  # Beide Problemarten
      '#000000',  # Co
      '#dddddd',  # Keine Probleme
      '#CCCCCC',  # Motivationale Probleme
      '#333333',  # Self
      '#666666',  # Shared
      '#bbbbbb'   # Verständnisbezogene Probleme  
    ),
    breaks = c(
      'Self',
      'Co',
      'Shared'
    )
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = .$xpos %>% unique(),
    labels = .$Problemzahl %>% unique(),
    expand = c(0, 0)
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    labels = function(x) str_replace(x, '\\.', ','),
    limits = c(0, 1.0),
    expand = c(0, 0)
  ) +
  ylab('Allgemeine Regulationsaktivität auf der Self-, Co-, und Shared Ebene\n(KI 95%)') +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    legend.position = 'top',
    legend.title = element_blank(),
    legend.spacing.x = unit(1, 'mm'),
    axis.title.x = element_blank()
  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would alter the code in your pipe before calling ggplot. Here's a nice example using the **formattable** package.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(formattable)

df1_long %>%
  mutate(val = formattable(val, digits = 2, format = "f")) %>%
  ggplot(
  ...
)
```

You can substitute whatever variable name for val, depending on which one you want to standardize to two decimal places.

Comment: When I enter your line of code, it only says: Error in formattable(val, digits = 2, format = "f") : object 'val' not found

Comment: Oh, I just noticed an error in your code. When using pipes, you don't need to specify the data argument. Remove the early instance of "data = .," and the "." in your initial pipe function (e.g. %.>% should be %>%). If that doesn't work, you may need to provide a reproducible example of your data for me to work with to see if I can help you troubleshoot.